# DOM getElementById as getting the whole element

Tags: javascript

why doesn't the gift just get the div id?

clicking modal is returning the whole div instead of just the id, why is that?

[jsfidle](https://jsfiddle.net/7h6b3j0a/8)

```js
function Modals(id, bt, show) {
  const modal = document.getElementById(id)
  modal.classList.add(show)

  modal.addEventListener("click", (elemento) => {
    if (elemento.target.id === modal) {
      modal.classList.remove(show)
      console.log(modal)
    }
  })

}


const comentarios = document.querySelector(".bt_comentarios")
comentarios.addEventListener("click", () => Modals("modal_comentarios",
  "bt_comentarios", "show"))
```

```html
<div id="modal_comentarios" class="modal fix"></div>
```

Comment: That code throws an error. Try providing a [mcve]

Comment: first thing with the code is that you are trying to look _into_ a function, because of scoping that will never work. it can only look _outside_ *look up lexical scoping*  also, as I am writing this, the answer has already been posted

Comment: Your code as it stands makes no sense at all. In `modal.classList.add(show)` you clearly show you expect `modal` to be an `HTMLElement`, whereas in `if (elemento.target.id === modal)` you are obviously trying to compare strings. I suggest you delete the code and start from scratch.

Comment: Re edit: The code still throws an exception and doesn't run. It doesn't return anything

Comment: Also, what does the name of the function you are trying to use tell you `getELEMENTById`? Essentially you are asking for a function that gives you `getIdById` - which is pure non-sense.

Comment: here is the example https://jsfiddle.net/7h6b3j0a/8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementById` will return an instance of `HTMLElement`. To get the id of the element, you'll need to use the `id` property.

```js
const main = document.getElementById('main');

console.log(main);
console.log(main.id);
```

```html
<div id="main">
</div>
```

### Using your snippet

```js
function Modals(id, bt, show) {
  const modal = document.getElementById(id)
  modal.classList.add(show)

  modal.addEventListener("click", (elemento) => {
    // EDIT: I used modal.id
    if (elemento.target.id === modal.id) {
      modal.classList.remove(show)
      // EDIT: I used modal.id
      console.log(modal.id)
    }
  })

}


const comentarios = document.querySelector(".bt_comentarios")
comentarios.addEventListener("click", () => Modals("modal_comentarios",
  "bt_comentarios", "show"))
```

```html
<div id="modal_comentarios" class="modal fix">
  <button id="modal_comentarios" class="bt_comentarios">Click Me!</button>
</div>
```

### What I changed

I added a few pieces to make the code go down the path of your if statement, and referenced the `modal.id` property instead of the instance of the `HTMLElement` itself. Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: If that were what OP is asking for, how do you explain `modal.classList.add(show)`?

Comment: @connexo did you read the question?

`why doesn't the gift just get the div id?

clicking modal is returning the whole div instead of just the id, why is that?`

`why is that?` Because you're not using the `id` property.

Comment: what I want is when I click on the modal it closes, so I use `target.id` to identify where it was clicked, only the result is an` ElementHTML` instead of the `ID`

Comment: `string`s have no `classList` property. How do you explain that part of the code? And also `modal.classList.remove(show)`? IMO that's just non-sense code.